# Shape-related vector fields

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

Assume that $M$  is  a surface in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. We denote   its  shape operator by $S$. A  vector field $X$ is  shape related to $Y$ if $S(X)=Y$.
(of course it is not an equivalent relation).

Assume that $X, Y$  are two vector fields on $S^{2}$ with the same singular points. Is there a surface $M$, diffeomorphic to $S^{2}$ via  a  diffeomorphism $\phi: M \to S^{2}$, such that $\phi^{*} (X)$ is shape related to $\phi^{*}(Y)$.

Comment: What is a shape operator?

Comment: @FanZheng If $M$ is  a  surface in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$  with Gauss normal vector  $N$, the shape operator at each point $p\in M$ is  a linear map $S$ on the tangent space $T_{p} M$  with $S(X)=\nabla_{X}^{N}$. Example: this operator is the identity operator for the round sphere.